# Angular project in another angular project: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: n.e is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I have created an angular 9 application and added the js files to another angular application and I get the error n.e is not a function in the console, after deploying the host app on IIS.

## Reproduction of the problem

1. create an angular 9 web component in the project a
2. create an angular application project b
3. use the angular component created in project a in project b
   Idea of web components app is to import the components to other project and work seamlessly.

## Error type:

```
main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: n.e is not a function
TypeError: n.e is not a function
    at loadChildren (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at un.loadModuleFactory (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at un.load (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at l.project (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at l._tryNext (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at l._next (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at l.next (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at d._subscribe (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at d._trySubscribe (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at d.subscribe (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at T (polyfills-es2015.61be2d396988ee9b9963.js:1)
    at T (polyfills-es2015.61be2d396988ee9b9963.js:1)
    at polyfills-es2015.61be2d396988ee9b9963.js:1
    at l.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.61be2d396988ee9b9963.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1)
    at l.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.61be2d396988ee9b9963.js:1)
    at a.runTask (polyfills-es2015.61be2d396988ee9b9963.js:1)
    at _ (polyfills-es2015.61be2d396988ee9b9963.js:1)
Bn @ main-es2015.75fe17eab98c55742615.js:1
```

Comment: Maybe try to debug with a non minified version of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just have a conflict with/within Webpack. If you switch the Angular builder to `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser`, you can use custom Webpack configuration like this:

```
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
              "mergeStrategies": {
                "externals": "replace"
              }
            },
...
```

And the custom config would just define unique jsonpFunction like this:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    jsonpFunction: 'projecta'
  }
}
```

Comment: @Oana how you solve this issue?can you show me example on stackblitz or show some snippets